# What is recommended way to use ansible with multipass?

Tags: multipass

By default `ansible` works with VMs in a network. `multipass networks` returns me `networks failed: The networks feature is not implemented on this backend.`

Probably switching to lxd backend would give me more network options including bridges. Before starting changing default qemu-based backend I want to ask for best practices.

What is a recommended way to set up ansible inventory to communicate to `multipass`-provisioned virtual machines?